# Using IShellBrowser::BrowseObject() in IShellFolder::EnumObjects()

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, shell-extensions

I have a Namespace Extension that makes webcalls to show its content.

When the Explorer wants to display the content of a folder it calls `EnumObjects` on my implementation. When there is an error making the webcall I want to return the User to the root of my NSE. Currently I call following code:

```
LPITEMIDLIST pidl = /*The piddle to navigate to, in my case root*/;

IShellBrowser* browser = (IShellBrowser*)SendMessage(m_hWnd, (WM_USER + 7), 0, 0);
if (browser != NULL) {

    hr = browser->BrowseObject(pidl, SBSP_SAMEBROWSER | SBSP_ABSOLUTE);
}
```

Sometimes the method call to `BrowseObject` fails with Invalid Access exception (x0000005).

We also used a variant that would use following variant:

```
hr = GetSite(IID_IServiceProvider, (void**)&serviceProvider);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return false;

IShellBrowser *browser;
hr = serviceProvider->QueryService(SID_SShellBrowser, &browser);
if(FAILED(hr))
    return false;
```

The site is obtaind through the interface `IObjectWithSite`. This also faild randomly. What I noticed was that when the webcall failed `m_site` was `NULL`.

`EnumObject` is called in a seperate thread from the explorer, to the UI will not freeze when I do the webcall. I assume I may not call Browse object from the thread that enums the folder, but how can I call browse on the correct thread?

Calling the `BrowseObject` in a new thread and wait 1 seccond will not lead to a crash. But I would not consider this hack as a valid solution.

Comment: After enumeration is done you will receive SFVM_BACKGROUNDENUM in the "main" thread. So my offer: when you create your IEmumIDList object pass pointer to bool var. Inside IEmumIDList set bool value if enumeration fails. When you receive SFVM_BACKGROUNDENUM check this bool value and if it true - call BrowseObject. But in theory your IShellFolder object can be released before  IEmumIDList object will try to set the value. So it is better to pass interfaced object instead of pointer to bool.

Comment: Please don't use sendmessage, it will make you incompatible with other NSE hosts.

Comment: @Anders Nobody is talking about SendMessage

Comment: @DenisAnisimov Except the OPs first code block.

Comment: @Anders Ohh my bad, you are right. I was thinking you wrote about my suggestion.

Comment: Surely this is actually a 0xC0000005 crash?  Very nasty.  These interfaces are not thread-safe, you must marshal the interface pointer.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov do you mean `SFVM_BACKGROUNDENUMDONE`? from the documentation it seems `SFVM_BACKGROUNDENUM` would be called on the beginning. But I'm not sure how to get the `IEnumIDList`, it was created on a different thread on a different object. I'll return it to the caller of `EnumObject` but dont get it as a parameter of `SFVM_BACKGROUNDENUM`. However I tested it always going to the root more or less infinit and id did not crashes anymore. So this seems to be the right direction.

Comment: @Anders The seccond one was the original, but had the problem that site of the object was not always set when needed. But I will look into that again, espacially if the `SendMessage` approach has problems.

Comment: @lokimidgard That message used to be documented in KB Q157247 (PRB: IShellFolder::CreateViewObject() Causes Access Violation) but it is not implemented by everyone so I would advise that you try get the browser with IServiceProvider first.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are not properly adding a reference to the COM interface you are using, which COULD cause it to be actually destroyed. So either use [CComPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), or at least call `AddRef`/ `Release` to hold a valid reference to the object.

Also if multiple threads are used, are you calling `CoInitialize` from all of them?